# Parse error handling in python

Tags: python, xml

```
import json
import requests
import pprint
from datetime import datetime
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
cursor = context.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table" )
for a in cursor.fetchall():
    data=a[0]
    root = ET.fromstring(a[1].encode('utf-16-be'))
    try:
        e = root.findall('test/element')
        f = root.findall('test/element1')
        for i,j in zip(e,f):
            char_id=i.text.rstrip()
            char_value=j.text.rstrip()
            Id = data
            tic_ID =char_id
            tic_value=char_value
            print(entityId,char_id,char_value)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table  VALUES (?,?,?)", (Id, tic_ID, 
            tic_value))
    except ValueError as error:
        raise ParseError(error)
```

How to handle xml parse error in this code to insert all the data without error data? some reason i would not use the lxml.

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: Actually it returns  "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity." error for some codes only.Need to know how to handle parseerror exception. Thanks

Comment: Then the input is not well-formed, which means it is not proper XML and the XML parser is correct in throwing an error.

Comment: Yes correct,Then How to handle the unproper xml and i need to load all the rows without that error xml rows?